# View assembly hash

Tags: .net, hash, assemblies

I have signed my assembly with strong key. I am able to locate public key in assembly manifest using ildasm. I am not able however to locate assembly hash which should be placed in assembly along with the public key.

Where can I find computed hash?

Kind regards
PK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the SDK strong naming tool you can run this on the command line

```
sn -T assemblyname
```

But the easiest thing for me is to simply open the assembly in [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) and then cut and paste the fully qualified assembly name.

[alt text http://www.deploylx.com/so/reflectorname.gif](http://www.deploylx.com/so/reflectorname.gif)